# How many equivalence classes are there in $J$.?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups, sylow-theory

Let $G$ be the symmetric group $S_5$ of permutations of five symbols. Consider the set $J$ of subgroups of $G$
that are isomorphic to the non-cyclic group of order $4$. Let us call two subgroups $H$ and $K$ belonging to $J$
as equivalent if they are conjugate (that is,  there exists $g $ such that $gHg^{-1}=K$). How many equivalence
classes are there in $J$.?

I have tried a lot but i found only one. But correct answer is two. But how ?

Comment: Friendly remark: $S_5$ is already a symbol for something known, so why to call it $G$ either? ;-)

Comment: Are you sure that there are two distinct classes? Are you allowed to conjugate by any $g \in S_5$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a hint: in one class, all the elements of order $2$ are double transpositions, in the other class, there are single transpositions.

Comment: But it asked about conjugacy of the group. Group of order 4 noncyclic group must have two transportation and one double transportation. Then how you get two different classes ?

Comment: No that's not true, some of the groups consists of the identity and three double transpositions.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** Originally, this answer made the mistaken assumption that the involutions that generate $V$ were transpositions in $S_5$.

The Klein four-group is generated by a pair of commuting <s>transpositions</s> involutions $s$ and $t$:
$$
V = \langle s, t \rangle = \{ 1, s, t, st \}.
$$

There are two cases to consider.

**Class 1: pair of commuting transpositions and a double transposition.**
An embedding of $V \hookrightarrow S_5$ is determined by selecting two non-overlapping pairs $\{a,b\}$, $\{c,d\}$. The subgroup consists of
$$
1, \quad (a\,b), \quad (c\,d), \quad (a\,b)(c\,d).
$$
But this double-counts the possible embeddings since the order you choose generating transpositions doesn't matter. Thus, the total number is
$$
\frac{1}{2}\binom{5}{2} \binom{3}{2} = \frac{1}{2} \cdot 10 \cdot 3 = 15.
$$

**Class 2: three double transpositions.**
An embedding of $V \hookrightarrow S_5$ is determined by selecting a set of four elements $\{a,b,c,d\}$. The subgroup consists of
$$
1, \quad (a\,b)(c\,d), \quad (a\,c)(b\,d), \quad (a\,d)(b\,c).
$$
Since all possible pairs of pairs are in the subgroup and any two can be generators, the count is exact and the total number is
$$
\binom{5}{4} = 5.
$$

---

All $15$ embedded copies of $V$ in Case 1 are conjugate, and all $5$ embedded copies of $V$ in Case 2 are conjugate, but embedded copies of $V$ from opposite classes are not conjugate. Why? Any two permutations are conjugate by some $g \in S_5$ if and only if they are of the same cycle shape. Explicitly, using cycle notation,
$$
g \, (a\,b) \, g^{-1} = (a'\,b') 
\qquad \text{where }
g(a) = a' 
\text{ and }
g(b) = b' 
$$
for Class 1, and
$$
g \, (a\,b)(c\,d) \, g^{-1} = (a'\,b')(c'\,d') 
\qquad \text{where }
g(a) = a', g(b) = b', g(c) = c',  
\text{ and }
g(d) = d' 
$$
for Class 2.

Comment: You are assuming that an element of order $2$ is a transposition...

Comment: D'oh! You're right. :-)

Comment: @verret, I edited my answer in light of your observation.